# Does an app have any minimum amount of disk space to itself?

Tags: ios

> Note: I'm not asking if there is a maximum, this question has been
>   asked before, I'm asking if there is any minimum left in reserve for an app.

My app downloads packages of content from the internet and I'm investigation how it should behave in low/no disk space conditions.

The packages have a time element, and if there's no space then the app could automatically delete old content in order to make space for new content. (The packages can expire, so them being removed without the user explicitly deleting them is standard behavior).

However this is pointless if all diskspace is shared between all apps and some other app has gobbled up all the available disk space on the device such that there's nothing at all left for my app. 
Is this scenario possible where another app can consume everything leaving nothing for my app? Or is there some amount of space reserved per app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no actual limit. I've been working with an app which has a 1.6GB footprint, and have had no problems. Essentially you work with what is available, and if someone else is being mean and taking all the space, there is not much you can do about it. A good policy could be to state 'My app will use 512mb of space on disk' or something like that, and then ensure that you never exceed that. Which will give you piece of mind that your app works to an upper limit. Rule of thumb on any mobile device, never assume you have enough space for anything, always check for failures when writing to disk, and have a policy to deal with it.

Further to this. If you want to guarantee that your app will always have enough space. Pick an upper limit of size (say 256 mb), and on install and first run of your app, create dummy files that eat up that much space on disk. Then, as you download useful data, replace the dummy files with the useful ones so that your app is always using that original amount of reserved space.

It also seems i misunderstood the question a little. The minimum reserved for your app is the space it will take up on a fresh download from the app store. That's it. If you only have 200mb free and you try to download a 300mb app, it wont let you.

Comment: "create dummy files that eat up that much space on disk" - I am curious, has anyone done this and had the app pass certification?

Comment: Well, there is not anything that apple can really do to stop you from doing this. There is not much difference between this and an app which downloads 1.6GB of images, 95% of which will probably never be used. Your app is not actually breaking any of the HIGS, and it could almost be seen as a good programming practice because you are ensuring your app will never exceed an upper bound, which most apps dont care about. However, i have not actually submitted an app that just eats space to reserve it, so i cannot say for certain if it would pass.

Comment: "Well, there is not anything that apple can really do to stop you from doing this." Yes, there is. They can see that you doing this and then prevent your app from being certified. I can see their argument being that it wastes bandwidth/battery/storage space. I'm not saying I disagree with your approach, I'm just saying it seems like it opens it up to being rejected.

Comment: True. My approach if i ran into this, would be to ship the app with a large amount of default data, showing essentially meaningless information to the user, but billed as 'sample data'. The app then replaces the sample data on the first run with real data, and hides the sample data, but it still exists on disk. That way apple cannot have an issue with it, because it's required sample data, but i still get my space reservation. Also i should not have phrased it that way, apple is notorious for blocking apps on a whim XD

Comment: You can't really replace "sample data" if it's a part of app. But yeah, creating dummy files might seem like a good idea until you consider a case where someone never launches your app again to download real content, and dummy files just cog up their space.

Comment: No as in, ship the sample data, then copy it to disk to validate your reason for having it on disk. It will eat up space, yes, but that's the whole point of this exercice. To guarantee space is there for you. I'm certainly not saying it's a nice approach, but it would work. Also i could make the argument about any app that a user downloads and never uses to its complete potential, it's wasting space for anything unused.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on the amount of space an app can consume.  An app could in theory use all the available disk space.

Comment: Thanks but my question isn't about maximum, its about minimum.

Comment: I have tested this by consuming all the disk space on my test phone then attempting to save a 1 mb file with my app and it failed.  In fact it looks like the os reserves a little space for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing on disk you could check amount of free disk space available and alert user accordingly.

```
-(uint64_t)getFreeDiskspacePrivate
{
uint64_t totalSpace = 0.0f;
uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0.0f;
NSError *error = nil;  
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

if (dictionary) {  
    NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes floatValue];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes floatValue];
    //NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
} /*else {  
    NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error code]);  
}  
*/
return totalFreeSpace;
}
```